# Unable to catch/throw error when executing a list of promises in a Sequelize transaction?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

In the below code I am trying to `upsert` to user records. If either record fails to `upsert`, I would like both records to be rolled back.

In the below code I force the second record to fail by setting `user_id = null`. However, it still hits the `then` block `return result;`. It does not catch/throw an error or rollback the transaction. I also see this error in my logs:

> ```
> Unhandled rejection SequelizeValidationError: notNull Violation: User.user_id cannot be null
>     at Promise.all.then
> ```

```
async function submitUsers(users) {
  return db.sequelize.transaction(async (tx) => {
     const queries = users.map((user, index) => {
        if (index == 1) {
            user.user_id = null;
        }
        User.upsert(user, tx);
     });

     await Promise.all(queries);
  }).then((result) => {
     return result;
  }).catch((e) => {
     throw e;
  });
}


const users = [ {user_id: 1}, {user_id: 2}];
await submitUsers(users);
```

Comment: where is your transaction block ending? you're not returning anything from your transaction block (that's why your `await Promise.all(queries)` is unhandled)

Comment: @stranded a lost a `}` when pasting the code. I edited to clarify

Comment: I think you need to explicitly catch `Promise.all(queries)` in the transaction function, the catch block outside doesn't take care of that.
I don't know how to explain it and I may be wrong but I think the block outside would only handle a promise returned by your function, and you're not returning any Promise explicitly (and your function will resolve with `null`)

Comment: @stranded I try changing my `Promise.all` like this, but neither `catch` block executes: `await Promise.all(queries).catch(e => {throw e});`

Comment: this would still just throw `e` inside the function and then it would again not be caught outside
I made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1g6uqzcL/) to explain it a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not returning your promises correctly. try this;

```
async function submitUsers(users) {
  return db.sequelize.transaction((tx) => {
     const queries = users.map((user, index) => {
        if (index == 1) {
            user.user_id = null;
        }
        return User.upsert(user, tx);
     });

     return Promise.all(queries);
  }).then((result) => {
     return result;
  }).catch((e) => {
     throw e;
  });
}
```

Comment: you're right. I was missing the `return` in my `map` function, so `queries` was an empty-ish array

Comment: glad I could help